# glVertexAttribFormat падает с ошибкой access violation

Tags: opengl

Есть исходник программы, которая использует OpenGL. При попытке запуска программа падает при вызове функции glVertexAttribFormat с ошибкой "Exception thrown at 0x00000000 in ******.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000.". Причём у других людей на компьютерах похоже эта программа работает. 
Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема и что можно сделать чтобы понять что происходит?

- ОС Windows 8.1
- Версия OpenGL 4.2
- Перед вызовом этой функции вызываю glGetError и получаю 0.

Comment: "Access violation executing location 0x00000000" намекает, что вызывается что-то по нулевому указателю. Проверьте, что функция определена.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку. Да действительно, эта функция на самом деле является указателем на функцию и этот указатель равен нулю. И функции рядом (glTexStorage2DMultisample, glTexStorage3DMultisample, glTextureView, glBindVertexBuffer, glVertexAttribBinding и так далее) тоже нулевые. Подскажите, почему это может быть и как это можно исправить? Используется загрузчик glad.

Answer (score 1):

После изучения файла glad.c входящего в состав проекта, выяснилось, что функция glVertexAttribFormat загружается только начиная с версии OpenGL 4.3. А у меня на компьютере, как оказалось стояла версия 4.2. После обновления драйвера видеокарты проблема решилась.